# RasPi SSH Not Working

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm using Mac OS X and trying to SSH into my pi. I have the pi boot up in front of me, and I can see that the IP address is `192.168.0.13`.

However, if I ping the router on the A Record address I assigned to it, it responds.

When I boot the Raspberry Pi up, it showed:

```
My IP address is 192.168.0.13
Raspian GNU/Linux 7 subdomain.domain.com tty1

subdomain login:
```

I was surprised that it showed the subdomain and domain on login (I'm a Linux newbie).

Ever since i set up the subdomain to go to my pi and set up the port forwarding and firewall exceptions on my router, I never really used the pi itself, I always SSH into it. It stopped working for the past week for some reason. There's nothing I installed recently except nginx, but that shouldn't affect it right?

Any troubleshooting advice? Can't seem to find anything newbie-friendly online.

Will be more than happy to provide more information, as I think I haven't provided enough here but don't know what else to add!

Many thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I was pinging the incorrect address! It's ...0.13 not ...1.13 :) Apologies!